# Как получить координаты элементы относительно блока в котором он находится ?

Tags: javascript, вёрстка, reactjs, frontend

Как при клике получить координаты элемента относительно блока в котором он находится ? Без jQuery.

Узнать top и left с картинки. Относительно блока center. При клике на синий квадрат.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Без jQuery можно на JavaScript:

```js
function position() {
  var obj = document.getElementById('inside'); // берем интересующий элемент  
  var posX = obj.offsetTop;  // верхний отступ эл-та от родителя
  var posY = obj.offsetLeft; // левый отступ эл-та от родителя
  console.log('x=[' + posX + '] y=[' + posY + ']'); // печатаем координаты
}
```

```css
.center {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
}

.inside {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 55px;
  margin-left: 51px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="center">
    <div id="inside" class="inside" onclick="position();">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Если посмотреть на позиционирование элемента:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Верх: `55 + 8 = 63`
Лево: `51 + 8 = 59`

Что и получили в результате: `x=[63] y=[59]`

Ссылки для ознакомления:

- [HTMLElement.offsetTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop)
- [HTMLElement.offsetLeft](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetLeft)
- [Node.parentElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement)

---

С использованием jQuery:

Для получения текущего положения относительно родительского элемента - можно использовать `position`. [position()](https://jquery-docs.ru/position/) - получает значение позиции элемента top и left относительно отступов его родителя. Также, есть метод [offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) для получения текущих координат элемента  по отношению к документу. С помощью [.offset() и .position()](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0) функций, можно узнавать координаты элемента на странице. Кроме этого, с помощью offset(), можно изменить координаты элемента. Имеется несколько вариантов использования функций, подробнее по ссылке: [Позиция элемента](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0).